# Undefined value when passing variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

Here is my code:

```
<%for(int i=0;i<post.size();i++){  %>

    <form  name="like">
    <input type="hidden" value="<%=post.get(i).getPostid() %>" name="sunny">
    <span id="display">
        <img src="Images/like_before.png" id="p1" onclick="change_like(<%=post.get(i).getPostid() %>)" width="10" height="10">like<span id="likecount" >
    </span>
<%}%>

<script>
    function change_like(postId) {
        console.log(postId)
    }
</script>
```

**Requirements** - Here I am trying to implement like functionality similar to facebook.

So for each post I will be having `post_id` >> then when I click the like button it will pass this id to `change_like` function >> so that I can update the like count & change the image of like button.

`post_id` is of int type.

**Problem** - But here it's printing `undefined`.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `<%=post.get(i).getPostid() %>` ? Is that a string?

Comment: You need to check the getPostid function is returning a value or not.  So there could be something wrong in getPostid function.

Comment: post is a pojo object. where I have post_id, post_text, TimeStamp etc. and yes the `post.get(i).getPostid()` is returning correct value.

Comment: Again, _What is the value_? Is it a string? Is it a number?

Comment: please specify the value and type of `<%=post.get(i).getPostid() %>`

Comment: Or simpler: post the actual generated HTML besides the JSP.

Comment: it's int value @cerbus

Comment: So then `getPostid` probably isn't returning the right value.

Comment: but if I print it there it's printing correct value. but inside function it's printing `undefined`

Comment: Can you add the rendered HTML to your question?

Answer (score 0):

if `<%=post.get(i).getPostid() %>` returns anything other than boolean or number , than you need to put quotes around it like `'<%=post.get(i).getPostid() %>'`